# "what is your first and last name" repeated sentence on signing applet

Tags: java, applet

I follow many tutorial on signing java applet but every time when i finished respond on questions, Same sentence was  repeated "what is your first and last name"?
How can I finis the process and get signed my applet

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg rsa -alias GermanyKey
```

this how I begin the process any help please?

Comment: Really you want to sign&use an applet? Chrome and Edge do not support them. Java 9 will remove browser plugin. But with a self-signed certificate won't work in any browser

Comment: what happens when you enter something that might look like your name?

Comment: @pedrofb, the signed jar can be used for webstart just as well...

Comment: Thanks @Stefan Hegny,  I did not know

Comment: @StefanHegny it asked me what is organization, entreprise, country.. when I respond all of them. It reasked me the same question.

Comment: @Manuel, might it be that you don't have write permission to the keystore file (default should be ~/.keystore)? Does it print any error before re-starting the questioning loop? Do you answer the last question correctly (`Is CN=some.name, OU=mgmt, O=some org., L=Seattle, ST=WA, C=US correct?
  [no]:` - you have to type `yes`)?